# Bootstrap button display getting cut by footer

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

footer.jsp has the following

```
<style>
    .footer {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        color: #324c70;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="footer"> Copyright MSCI 2019. All rights reserved.
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

this footer is included in a page that has a bootstrap button just above the footer and it is getting cut

```
<button type="button" class="main" id="create" name="create" value="Create Change" style="background-color: #37617A;color: white;padding: 8px 20px;
                    margin: 8px 0; border: none; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;" >
                Create Change
            </button>
```

Attached image showcases the issue I am facing

Comment: I believe you should counter the lost height of the `fixed` footer with some padding. Ideally bottom padding on the container before the footer.

Comment: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhH5J.png

Comment: @TimVermaelen Thanks this resolved my issue!